# How to place jaxb.properties in META-INF or resources folder in spring boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb, properties-file, meta-inf

I have a spring boot project which have a model class called **Message.java** and have a **jaxb.properties** file in the same package where Message.java is situated. This works fine.

But is there a way where i can place my jaxb.properties file in **META-INF** or **resources** folder. I tried placing under **/META-INF** folder but isn't working.

Placing **.properties** file in a package consisting of only model classes looks unstructured.

Can anyone suggest on this how to achieve this.

Comment: Why do you need ad jaxb.properties? Can you show the content?

Comment: I am using jaxb.properties to bind jaxb.properties. The jaxb.properties content is as follow:- 
**javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory**

If i don't use jaxb.proeprties file then the @XMLPath annotation over a java property isn't working.
Ex:- I have a java property as shown below:
**@XmlPath("FICdtrf/GrpHdr/MsgId/text()")**
**String msg_Id;**
Then the XML generated without jaxb.properties file will be:-
**<msgId>202</msgId>**
Hence using jaxv.properties will produce XML as follows:-
**<FICdtrf><GrpHdr><MsgId>202</MsgId></GrpHdr></FICdtrf>**

Comment: I see. It's by convention that the jaxb.properties are in the same place as the corresponding class. You could remove it but then you have to set the class name when doing marshalling or unmarshalling